# Where do I put properties files for running JUnit tests on Maven?

Tags: maven-2, maven, junit

I'm using Maven 3.0.3.  I'm running the "mvn test" command, in which my test files are in the standard place (src/test/java).  Where do I put properties files so that they get picked up by Java's "getResourceAsStream" method?  I tried placing my properties files in both src/main/resources and src/test/resources, but my JUnit test isn't finding them.  Here's how I want to load the tests ...

```
final InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("my.properties");
```

but this returns null.  I'm using JUnit 4.8.  Any ideas?  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for me if I use `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/my.properties")`.

Without the `/` prefix, the path is relative to your class's package, so you'd have to put the properties file in a path like `src/test/resources/com/mycompany/mypackage/my.properties`.